# Gollum-wiki error from start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gollum-wiki

After succesful installation I do
sudo gollum  --port 80 and get error

```
 Gollum::InvalidGitRepositoryError at /
       Gollum::InvalidGitRepositoryError
         file: git_layer_grit.rb location: rescue in initialize line: 280
        BACKTRACE
        (expand)
        JUMP TO: GET POST COOKIES ENV
         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
  si.service(req, res)
         /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
      server.service(req, res)
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
      block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, You have to create git repository.

$ git init

$ gollum --port 80

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`gollum --port 80 --gollum-path /your/repo/directory`

Or run the command from inside your git repo

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the git repo as an argument to `gollum`, like this:

`gollum --port 80 /home/gollum/wiki`

See `gollum --help`.